# Click on button if paragraph has specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this HTML here:

```html
<div id="team_log_actual" class="log">
<p><img src="/img/item/item_ejector.png"> <b>[<span style="color: #0FF">Owner</span>] <span style="color: #0FF;">Someusername</span></b> placed a block.</p>
<p><img src="/img/item/helm.png"> <b>[<span style="color: #0FF">Owner</span>] <span style="color: #0FF;">Someusername</span></b> used item</p>
</div>
```

In that HTML you can see two paragraph elements. These paragraphs can be created at random intervals and can be append to the `<div>` with the class "log". You can also see each paragraph can contain specific text strings. Like "used item".

Is there anyway I could check each paragraph for specific strings, and if it matches do a function for that current paragraph element? Like maybe change the `.innerHTML` or click a button or the paragraph itself.? ETC...

Comment: Yes, but what have you tried so far? This is not a place to ask someone to code for you. Also, at what time do you need to make those operations? Have a look at jQuery's `text()` method and `indexOf`

Comment: You could potentially use a MutationObserver to check the content of the elements as they are added to the parent `div`, however a much better pattern would be to use an event system, where an event is raised when the new content is added to the DOM, then you can simply hook to that event and find whatever content you need.

Comment: Sure you can check what they contain - use `indexOf` on innerHTML or innerText … _“These paragraphs can be created at random intervals and can be append to the <div> with the class "log".”_ - so you’d need something that checks periodically (setInterval), or you need to work with a MutationObserver.

Answer (score 1):

Use `indexOf` to find the desire string.

```js
$('#team_log_actual').find('p').each(function(index, element) {
  var str1 = $(this).text();
  var str2 = "used item";
  if (str1.indexOf(str2) != -1) {
    $(this).addClass('YourClass'); // What ever you want to do if match. For eg. I add class.
  }
});
```

```css
.YourClass {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="team_log_actual" class="log">
  <p><img src="/img/item/item_ejector.png"> <b>[<span style="color: #0FF">Owner</span>] <span style="color: #0FF;">Someusername</span></b> placed a block.</p>
  <p><img src="/img/item/helm.png"> <b>[<span style="color: #0FF">Owner</span>] <span style="color: #0FF;">Someusername</span></b> used item</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add event for modify it when its created

or after its created like this:

```
$('#team_log_actual').find('p').each(function(index) {
    // enter code here

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the text using `.includes()` inside `.each()`.

**Demo:**

```js
var dynamicP = `<p><img src="/img/item/helm.png"> <b>[<span style="color: #0FF">Owner</span>] <span style="color: #0FF;">Someusername</span></b> used item 2</p>`;
$('.log').append(dynamicP);
$('p').each(function(){
  if($(this).text().includes('used item')){
    $(this).css('cursor','pointer'); // You can also add some style as well
    $(this).on('click',  function(){
      console.log('Cliked allowed on this paragraph');
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="team_log_actual" class="log">
<p><img src="/img/item/item_ejector.png"> <b>[<span style="color: #0FF">Owner</span>] <span style="color: #0FF;">Someusername</span></b> placed a block.</p>
<p><img src="/img/item/helm.png"> <b>[<span style="color: #0FF">Owner</span>] <span style="color: #0FF;">Someusername</span></b> used item</p>
</div>
```